# Get first descendant with django-mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm using

```
try:
    my_group.get_descendants().filter(number=number)[0]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

when I want to get all groups with `my_group` as an ancestor but only choose the first. Can I make the database do this for me? I'm thinking of something like

```
try:
    my_group.get_descendants().filter(number=number).earliest()
except Group.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

but am I sure that `.earliest()` gives me the node 'closest to the ancestor'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) method, it does exactly what you want:

```
my_group.get_descendants().filter(number=number).first()
```

Comment: but with `first()` it will result in `None` if the queryset is empty and doesn't it return an entire queryset? Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes if the queryset is empty then `first()` returns `None`.  And yes, this is the best way to do it.